# Help with inequality with one unknown

Tags: inequality, education

Please could you help how to solve the inequality
$(\sqrt{x-9})(2^{x-8}+3^{x-9}-9)\geq 0$

Comment: It's not clear what the argument of the radical is.

Comment: Is it $$\sqrt{x-9}(2^{x-8}+3^{x-9}-9)\geq 0$$?

Comment: What did you try? Did you try $x=9,10,11$ for example?

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner yes, this is it

Comment: $$x=9$$ is one solution, to solve $$2^{x-8}+3^{x-9}-9\geq 0$$ you will Need a numerical method

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = t+9$, then the radical needs $t \geqslant 0$.  $t=0$ is a solution obviously, for others, we are left to solve $2\cdot 2^t+3^t\geqslant 9$.  Note LHS is increasing, and starting from $3<9$, so there is a unique $a>0$ s.t. $t \in [a, \infty)$ are all solutions, i.e. the full solution set is $x\in \{9\}\cup[a+9, \infty)$, where $2\cdot 2^a+3^a=9$.

To find $a$, you will need to use numerical methods, it’s about $1.288...$.